# How to configure Babel to only output es2017/modern code?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, config, es6-modules

I'm trying to configure web with [optimize-plugin](https://github.com/developit/optimize-plugin) and babel to create module/nomodule bundles. In fact, I son't mind too much the nomodule thing, but I'd like to be sure to correctly configure babel to output es2017 code. In several tuts, for example [this one](https://web.dev/publish-modern-javascript/), I've found a preset like 'es2017', but from babel docs it seems it's not supported anymore. Instead, I should use `'@babel/preset-env'` along with a browserlist config. It's not really clear to me how I should compose the browserlist. For now, I would say something like:

```
module.exports = { 
  presets : [ '@babel/preset-env' ],
  
  targets : {
    browsers: "last 2 versions, not dead, not IE 11",
    esmodules: true
  }
};
```

But not really sure.. Can someone tell me the perfect one? :)

Comment: `last 2 versions` for IE is `IE 10` and `IE 11`, only one of which you rule out. Change that to `not IE <= 11`, and remove the `not dead` part.

Comment: Ok thank you. And should I keep esmodules: true? That is not clear to me, since in theory, last 2 versions do support modules and thus babel shuold output/keep modules even without that option. No clear from the docs.

Comment: Mmm, not dead should phase out IE10, that's the reason for only IE11.

Comment: That surely depends on the region.

Comment: I don't think so. 'dead' means that does not receive security updates anymore. Like ie10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found an answer by reading [this code](https://github.com/philipwalton/rollup-native-modules-boilerplate/blob/master/rollup.config.js) that comes from [here](https://philipwalton.com/articles/using-native-javascript-modules-in-production-today/). It's simply:

```
'last 2 Chrome versions',
'last 2 Safari versions',
'last 2 iOS versions',
'last 2 Edge versions',
'Firefox ESR',
```

And not using the `esmodules` target due to this issue, as reported in  comments on linked code above:

https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8809

Even if probably with babel 8 we will be able to use it:

https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/12189

Comment: There's so many more browsers than the ones you list. E.g. the QQ browser has a larger market share than Firefox and Safari combined.

Comment: Yes this is written in browserslist docs exactly. I don't mind too much: if it's ok for the above browsers, will be for latest QQ too. I also currently do not mind chinese market too much.